# Check if client has already voted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a poll site. And for making sure that people can't vote twice I'm saving their IP with the ID for the poll in a database. But this requires me to send the IP from the client to the server to retrieve the data out of the database. I am doing this all on the button: Vote so it checks when you click vote.

Now I am using Express and socketio and Node.js. I can't really figure out how to retrieve the IP.

The user does not have to register to vote or create a poll.

The method above might not be the best one and I think there might be a better one. So my question is:

What would be the best way to check if someone has already voted on a poll.

Comment: There's no any even near reliable way to check, whether a person has voted or not. IPs are not connected to humans, rather they are connected to machines.

Comment: Depending on internet connection, some people get new IP each day for example. So, I would also store the unique (poll) ID into client's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and the chosen vote ID. Once user requests the initial poll data, you will have 2 elements to compare if he already voted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the IP address, inside your express application:

```
app.get('/ip', function (req, res) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

    //do whatever you want with it
});
```

And to answer your question, personally I'd require the user to type some sort of unique identification, like a university id number, tax number (thats how we're identified here in Brazil for example), anything that you can guarantee is unique to only one individual in your area of interest.

If you can't get something like that, I guess you'd have to register your users.